# How to insert values coming from python into the body section of an html file?

Tags: python, html, file, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getnames():
    #i = 1
    #for i in range(1,60):
        url = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1')#{}.format(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,"html.parser")
        games = (soup.find('div',"leftcol large").find_all('a',"search_result_row ds_collapse_flag"))
        for game in games:
            picture = game.find('div',"col search_capsule").img
            name_of_game = game.find("span","title")
            discount = game.find('div',"col search_discount responsive_secondrow")
            from_price = game.find('div',"col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow").span.strike
            to_price_w_from = game.find("div","col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow").span.extract()
            to_price = game.find('div', "col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow")
            print(name_of_game)
        #i+=1
```

this is the code I use to get the names of the games at discount. When I run the function, what it prints out is that

```
<span class="title">No Man's Sky</span>
<span class="title">Little Nightmares</span>
<span class="title">Kerbal Space Program</span>
<span class="title">Mafia III</span>
<span class="title">Mafia II</span>
       ..............
```

There is nothing wrong with it. I want to make a container that contains some of the information above and send it to the "index.html" file which is in the same folder. Again, there is nothing wrong with making a container but the problem is **I can't send it into the body part of html file**. I have tried a few things but couldn't manage to send it. How can I insert what I have into the body section of html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to make a new *BeautifulSoup* object of the existing *index.html* file. Modify it with the new data, then overwrite *index.html* with the string representation of the object. *[Modifying the tree section of the bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree)* provides info on the various methods available to do this.

A simple example.

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I want to insert here-->
</body>
</html>
```

*Code to modify the file*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'), 'html.parser')
p_tag = soup.new_tag("p")
p_tag.string = 'This is the new paragraph'
soup.body.append(p_tag)
with open("index.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

*Modified index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- I want to insert here-->
<p>This is the new paragraph</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a index file as a template with replaceable code holder - a special pythonic tag. Read the index template and replace your content at specific place. Replace index.html

Following quick example

--- index template ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-1 mb-1">

    <div id="main_ad_block">
        <div class="card-columns mt-1 mb-1" id="sub_ad_block">
            %(ads_block)s
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

--- python code ---

```
INDEX_TEMPLATE = './www/templates/index_template.html'
INDEX_FILE = './www/templates/index.html'

    str_ads = """<span class="title">No Man's Sky</span>
                    <span class="title">Little Nightmares</span>
                    <span class="title">Kerbal Space Program</span>
                    <span class="title">Mafia III</span>
                    <span class="title">Mafia II</span>"""

    # read template index file
    with open(INDEX_TEMPLATE, 'r') as input_file:
        str_template = input_file.readlines()

    str_template = [line % {'ads_block': str_ads} for line in str_template]

    with open(INDEX_FILE, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(str_template)
```

Have a look at the;

```
str_ads = """<span class="title">No Man's Sky</span>
                    <span class="title">Little Nightmares</span>
                    <span class="title">Kerbal Space Program</span>
                    <span class="title">Mafia III</span>
                    <span class="title">Mafia II</span>"""
```

this is your html to insert into index.

and,

get python code to insert your html to replaceable code holder "%(ads_block)s",

```
str_template = [line % {'ads_block': str_ads} for line in str_template]
```

of course, you may need to tweak this to suite your requirement.